# XE8 Twebbrowser local img files

Tags: android, ios, delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-xe8

I am using Twebbrowser in Delphi XE8.

I am downloading images from Amazon S3 and put in a folder called downloadfolder

```
mobfolder:=System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim ;
DownloadFolder:= mobfolder +'download'+  PathDelim;
```

How can I open a file in that location from Twebbrowser

Tried

```
WebBrowser1.URL:='file://'+DownloadFolder+filename;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was related to Jquery for mobile, Jquery can not access local files.

to handle it I need

1. a webserver local in my app so I can use http or
2. upload image to a server and then
   show it in my webbrowser app.

I did the uploading , so now I upload the image to  S3 and then show it in my webAPP , its now working.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine();` function - it's recomended for creating folders on FMX

```
DownloadFolder := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath,download);
DownloadFileName := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(Downloadfolder,filename);
WebBrowser1.URL :='file://'+DownloadFileName;
```

In some case of loading files its help.

Answer (score 1):

You should deploy your file. Use Deploy manager for it.

If you trying to write multiplatform application - use TPath from System.IOUtils for works with file's name.
For example

```
uses
  System.IOUtils
...
  LFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'yourfile.html');
...
```

After it - check file using fileexist method and call URL.

```
  if FileExist(LFileName) then
    Webbrowser1.URL := 'file://' + LFileName
  else
    Label1.Text := 'file ' + LFileName + ' not found';
```

Comment: What do you mean with "you should deploy your file"?

Comment: I mean that you should place your file on device into some folder. Best way - use Deployment manager.